# Phrase to describe "re-reading an email you wrote, because it is just that good"

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions, phrase-requests

I want to describe a recurring situation that happens in the modern day when people craft an email that is "perfect" in that person's mind, and they end up re-reading the sent message over and over.

Maybe they are re-reading the email because they are satisfied that all the details are covered, or to appreciate the email's conciseness and focus, or even appreciate the tone and word choice.

Relish is the closest I've found, but since I'm describing a person who enjoys the written word, I would hope there is a way to phrase it in a way that is more poetic to the situation. E.g. the word or phrase itself should have special meaning, intellectual or otherwise, to writers.

Comment: "relish" is excellent, BTW.

Answer (score 3):

I read it again, **basking in the glory** of my words like a (occupation) returning triumphantly from (some competition).

Comment: hmm basking in the ___ might work...

Answer (score 2):

Relish is not a bad word for it.

Or perhaps **admire**.

> He admired his (own) accomplishment with (a sense of) relish and hubris.

There probably are quite a few idiomatic/poetic expressions to describe this.

Answer (score 2):

Revelling in your own linguistic artistry.

Comment: yum.  This is pleasant. I immediately smiled when I read this